# Hover on parent does not affect mark tag CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I apply hover style from a parent container, such as div or anchor, to a mark tag? I know this is default behavior for other elements nested inside a parent like span. However, it is not working for me when I use a mark tag.

Here are three examples, 1) div with mark, 2) anchor with mark, 3) anchor with span. If you hover the parent, but outside the child, it changes the span, but not the mark.

```
<div>
  Outside div <mark>inside mark</mark>
</div>

<a>
  Outside anchor <mark>inside mark</mark>
</a>
<br>
<a>
  Outside anchor <span>inside span</span>
</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ku6drqt5/

I would love to know what is special about the mark tag that is preventing this from working, and how I might correct it. Otherwise, simple workarounds are welcome.

Note: I am using Chrome v48.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the color has to be specifically set on a `mark` element as it's not directly inherited.

Per *Joseph*'s comment

> ...the default browser/user-agent `color` for the `mark` element is set as `black`

Just as the default background color is `yellow`*.

<sup>* this appears be the agreed defaults for Chrome, Firefox and IE although I cannot locate any *requirement* for this to be the case.</sup>

> So when you change the parent:hover color, the user agent styling is still more specific. `<span>` does not have a color set, so it inherits the color specified on parent:hover

A workaround

```css
.parent:hover {
  color: red;
}
.parent:hover mark {
  color: currentColor; /* or inherit as noted in the other answer */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Outside div
  <mark>inside mark</mark>
</div>

<a class="parent">
  Outside anchor <mark>inside mark</mark>
</a>
<br>
<a class="parent">
  Outside anchor <span>inside span</span>
</a>
```

---

Depending on your requirement you might like to add this to your CSS reset.

```
mark {
  color:inherit;
}
```

[**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ku6drqt5/4/)

Comment: I would assume this is because the user agent styling for <mark> defines a color. So when you change the parent:hover color, the user agent styling is still more specific. <span> does not have a color set in the user agent CSS, so it inherits the color specified on parent:hover.

Comment: @Joseph Many thanks...I was just searching for a definitive reference to include but your's is a good explanation in the interim.

Comment: My assumptions are by no means definitive :-) a recent user agent stylesheet for webkit-based browsers can be found here, if anyone is wondering: http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css which specifies styling for the <mark> element

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and explanation. It finally clicked for me once I realized the user agent was setting mark to black. I also was using the wrong selector in my own failed attempts `.parent mark:hover` instead of `.parent:hover mark`.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how your user agent (browser) styles the `<mark>` element. Chrome has these defaults:

```
background-color: yellow;
color: black;
```

The easiest way to reset this, is through adding this to your css:

```
.parent:hover mark {
    background-color: inherit;
    color: inherit;
}
```